# Unity 3.2.0 - Project path issue with Visual Studio Community

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I'm a newbie to Unity and Visual Studio Community and I'm using Unity Hub 3.2.0 with editor version 2021.3.8f1. I am running into this issue with the project path.[Error code at the bottom of Unity Editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XdHTM.png)

I have no idea what this means really even when researching. I'm also not sure if this affects a game being built in the editor.

Could someone please explain what this means and how I can fix this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well what is the path to your project ??

Comment: _"Project path contains special characters, which can be an issue when opening Visual Studio"_ - is pretty self-explanatory.   No Unity expertise required there.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The warning means: The project path has illegal characters.

You can modify the path of the project.The project storage path contains only English strings.

[image]

In addition to saving in the location set in the above figure, it will also be saved in the C drive. (C:\Users\lantian\AppData\LocalLow\DefaultCompany), as shown in the following figure.

[image]